# GWT 2.5.1 Compile always throws Java Heap Space Error

Tags: gwt

Whenever I compile GWT 2.5.1 application. by right click on project and doing Run As-> Web Application (GWT Super Dev Mode), it never fully compiles and throws Java heaps space full error. Even when I increase the heap space size to as max as it can be, it is still throwing the same error. No matter what memory value I give, it always failes with heap space error. Can anyone help out?

Comment: GWT 2.5.1 is old and it consume much memory, try to update to version 2.8

Answer (score 1):

How did you increase the heap space? In IntelliJ for example you need to explicitely give the build process more space:

`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Build process heap size`